# django_tables2 sorting not working on foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-tables2

I am new to Django tables but I have a model which look like this:

```
class EmployeeResponse(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to populate the Employee response data using `django_tables2` for which I created a Table which looks like this:

```
class EmployeeResponseTable(tables.Table):
    user = tables.Column(orderable=True)
    employee = tables.Column(orderable=True)
    question = tables.Column(orderable=False)
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeResponse
        exclude = ['id']
        sequence = ("user","employee", "question")
```

Everything works fine but sorting is not happening for user and employee column. Please help me to resolve this. Also I am populating user and employee data like

```
    data =[]
    employee_responses = EmployeeResponse.objects.all()
    for er in employee_responses:
        data.append({"user": er.user, "employee": er.employee, "question": er.question})
```

and then pushed all data using

```
table = EmployeeResponseTable(data)
```

I don't know why sorting is not happening. pleas help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `RequestConfig` object.

```
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
table = EmployeeResponseTable(data)
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
```